AvaloniaUI cursor movement
I am doing a small project in avalonia in Win10 and I would like to be able to move my mouse with an event. Is that possible?
I'm asking because all I've seen with cursor interaction is SUBSCRIPTION to the cursor, or changing it's appearance.
For now I've added this to a view to move the cursor:
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(out System.Drawing.Point lpPoint);

But I'd rather have a more multiplatform-suitable option.

Alternatively, you can turn to the Headless Platform and use the built-in mechanism:
Window.MouseMove(Point point, MouseButton button, RawInputModifiers modifiers)​
Window.KeyPress(Key key, RawInputModifiers modifiers, PhysicalKey physicalKey, string? keySymbol)​

